# What is a “service lecture”?

Tags: faculty-application, terminology

On a form for a job application, I am being asked to list, among others, what “service lectures” I have given. What exactly is meant by that? What does, or does not, count as a service lecture?

Comment: I might presume it means a lecture done in service, rather than in employment. For example as part of a public outreach series or in a volunteer capacity at a community school.

Comment: Which country and subject area is the job in?

Answer (score 12):

In my experience, *service lecture* is used to refer to a lecture (course) about your field given to students of another field, usually an introductory course to give those students the basics that they need for their studies.

For example, at my university, there is a course *Physics for Chemists, Biologists, and Geologists* which is organised by the department of physics and given by a physics professor and which teaches essential concepts of physics to students of the named fields. In contrast to “physics for physicists” lectures, the department of physics does not benefit from the effort put into this lecture as it’s not teaching its own students. Thus giving this lecture is a mere service to the departments of chemistry, biology and geology.

Of course, to be sure about the intended meaning, you would have to ask the issuers of the form.

Comment: The equivalent translation is used in Brazil, with the same meaning. Probably France too, but I'm unsure.

Comment: In Italy as well, "corsi di servizio".

Comment: +1 for "ask the issuers of the form". If this question were asked at [the Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), we would close it and tell you to ask the recruiter.

Comment: My undergrad and graduate department (Aerospace Eng/Engineering Mechanics) taught the Statics and Dynamics courses for all the other engineering departments at UT Austin as a service. They weren't clearly labeled as such, but everyone knew that was how they were structured. So the MEs, ArchEs, CEs, etc, all took them from us. The classes were, appropriately, huge. Physics was/is the same, but taught by the Physics department without a special label. Calculus, Diff. Eq., and Vector Calc. as well, but by the Math department. This might not be clear on a CV if your uni doesn't clearly label them.

Answer (score -3):

As this is for a job application in a presumably academic position, reaching out for more information in a state of ignorance demonstrated you grasp one of the most basic academic principles and virtues. This would do more to improve your reputation with said institution than hurt it.

Even outside that, there does not seem to exist a general consensus as to what the term means. I've seen references mentioning similar definitions to the other answers, but also places where service lectures are described as the mandatory lectures given during a PhD track.